# AngularJS - Filter empty objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a $scope.myData object that contain a chunk of data. What i am trying to do is display the data but filter out the nulls and empty strings:

```
$scope.myData = [
    {
       "ID" : "001",
       "Message" : "test test test test"
    },
    {
       "ID" : "002",
       "Message" : "test test test test"
    },
    {
       "ID" : "003",
       "Message" : "test test test test"
    },
    {
       "ID" : "004",
       "Message" : "test test test test"
    },
    {
       "ID" : "005",
       "Message" : " "
    },
    {
       "ID" : "006",
       "Message" : "test test test test"
    },
    {
       "ID" : "007",
       "Message" : "test test test test"
    },
    {
       "ID" : "007",
       "Message" : null
    }
]
```

I can perform an ng-repeat on the above and filter null's via:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData | filter:{Message: '!!'}">
    {{ data.ID }}
    {{ data.Message }}
</div>
```

But how can i filter the empty strings e.g:

```
"Message" : " "
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use ng-if there.if message is not empty show items.

Comment: @Creator - do you have an example?

Answer (score 59):

We can simply use ng-if here:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData " ng-if="data.Message">
 {{ data.ID }}
 {{ data.Message }}
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: I edited this answer to take into account that a string with one space is truthy; therefore you must check against the negative condition of that case as well

Comment: Better solution than having to create a customer filter.

Answer (score 19):

You can use a function instead of an object like this

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData | filter:emptyOrNull">
  {{ data.ID }}
  {{ data.Message }}
</div>
```

And in the controller

```
$scope.emptyOrNull = function(item){
  return !(item.Message === null || item.Message.trim().length === 0)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Well you can create a custom filter:

```
.filter('hasSomeValue', [function(){
    return function(input, param) {
        var ret = [];
        if(!angular.isDefined(param)) param = true;

        angular.forEach(input, function(v){
            if(angular.isDefined(v.Message) && v.Message) {
                v.Message = v.Message.replace(/^\s*/g, '');
                ret.push(v);
            }
        });

        return ret;
    };
}])
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData | hasSomeValue: data.Message">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2aZjr/7/)

Comment: This is a bit more complex than @Edminsson's answer but is slightly better as it doesn't pollutes the scope with a function whose only function is to filter.

Answer (score 4):

You can use '' charter. 
Try check like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData | filter:{Message: ''}">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an angular filter for this:

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RUkSf/)

Code Snippet:

```
.filter('filterData',function(){
    return function(data) {
        var dataToBePushed = [];
        data.forEach(function(resultData){
            if(resultData.Message && resultData.Message != " ")
                dataToBePushed.push(resultData);
        });
        return dataToBePushed;
    }
});
```

Comment: it won't work on double space "   " or something like that

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to filter out values in an object that are empty, you could create a custom filter and filter each based on the value.

Something like this:

```
.filter("notEmpty",
function () {
    return function (object) {
        var filteredObj = {};
        angular.forEach(object, function (val, key) {
            if (val != null) {
                if (typeof(val) === "object") {
                    if (Object.keys(val).length > 0) {
                        filteredObj[key] = val;
                    }
                } else if (typeof(val) === "string") {
                    if (val.trim() !== "") {
                        filteredObj[key] = val;
                    }
                } else {
                    filteredObj[key] = val;
                }
            }
        });
        return filteredObj;
    };
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/t6jr1b2k/)

You could also use the ng-if directive and a function that parses the objects as you see fit.