# ng-repeat filter for where an attribute is undefined

Tags: angularjs, filter

I was hoping this would be really simple in angular.

I have an list with translators and other users

```
[{user: 'a',languages:['french','english','spanish']},
{user: 'b'}]
```

I then have an ng-repeat where I only want to display the users who have languages

```
ng-repeat="translator in users | filter: {languages}"
```

but unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to filter by the existence of an attribute. 
I've tried all manner of

```
{languages:'!undefined'}
{languages.length > 0}
{languages.length:'!0'}
```

I don't want to have to write an external filter for this as I'm sure it's possible in angular, I'm just not able to get the lingo right.

Comment: I think you should keep the same structure for all the elements in your users array, even if language is empty for user 'b'.

Comment: are you opposed to writing a function on scope?

Comment: Different solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24992197/257470

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="translator in users | filter : { languages : '!!' }">
```

### Explanation:

Consider a list as below:

```
$scope.items = [
    {
        propertyOne: 'a',
        propertyTwo: 'hello'
    },
    {
        propertyOne: 'b', 
        propertyTwo: null
    },
    {
        propertyOne: 'c', 
        propertyTwo: undefined
    },
    {
        propertyOne: 'd'
    }
];
```

`'!!'` filters out objects having a certain property or objects having a certain property that is not undefined or null:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter : { propertyTwo : '!!' }">
    {{item.propertyOne}}
</div>
<!-- outputs: a -->
```

`'!'` filters out objects not having certain property or objects having a certain property that is undefined or null:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter : { propertyTwo : '!' }">
    {{item.propertyOne}}
</div>
<!-- outputs: b c d -->
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EEokRlO2GoEgvge6iBAC?p=preview)**

Note: It does not work for properties with values like 0, false or empty string('').

EDIT: previous answer was different from the plunkr example. I fixed them by swapping '!!' and '!'.

Comment: can you please explain it?

Comment: @ebramtharwat Explanation added.

Comment: @ebramtharwat, to further the explanation, as many people are unaware, !! is absolute truth, return true for any value not null or undefined, hence the reason values like 0 and empty string return true. Not sure why false would return though?

Very good use of that, hadn't even considered it.

Comment: `!!` does not seem to work on angular 1.3.15 when the property type is boolean

Comment: Did you reverse your ! and !! operators in the examples or explanation?  (The results don't match your statements about the effects)

Comment: yes, the author probably had a typo. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.hasLanguage = function(user) {
       return user.hasOwnProperty('languages');
    }
 });
```

HTML:

```
ng-repeat="translator in users | filter: hasLanguage"
```