# Angularjs Filter not working when the property is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have the following setup

```
  $scope.array = 
    [
      {propertyA: "test", 
       propertyB: {
                   propertyC: [true, true, false]
                  }
      },
      {propertyA: "test2"},
      {propertyA: "test3"}
    ]
```

and then

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array| filter :{propertyB: ''} :true">
     {{item.propertyA}}
</div>
```

So the problem is:

1. this setup does not display anything
2. if i change to `|filter :{propertyB: '!!'} :true` it does not display anything
3. if i change to `|filter :{propertyB: undefined} :true` it displays everything

I can`t figure it out.

Target: I want to display the items which have the `propertyB` undefined and in other case the other way around.

Edit 1: If I iterate over the array with `angular.equals(item.propertyB, undefined)` I get `false, true, true`

Edit 2: [jsfiddle UPDATED](https://jsfiddle.net/20vbr950/7/)

Edit 3: I have updated the question

Comment: Plese add jsfiddle or plunkr

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177004/ng-repeat-filter-for-where-an-attribute-is-undefined

Comment: Just remove true and everything works with ! and !!.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I endded up doing this.

```
.filter('undefinedProperties', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
        var checkProperty = function (property, returnUndefined) {
            if (returnUndefined) {
                if (property !== undefined) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                if (property === undefined) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };
        return function (input, propertyArray, returnUndefined) {
            if (angular.isArray(propertyArray)) {
                if (angular.isArray(input) && input.length > 0) {
                    angular.forEach(propertyArray, function (property) {
                        for (var i = input.length; i-- > 0;) {
                            if (checkProperty(input[i][property], returnUndefined)) {
                                input.splice(i, 1);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                return input;
            } else {
                throw "PropertyArray is not an array";
            }
        };
    }])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.array = 
[
  {propertyA: "test", propertyB: "test2"},
  {propertyA: "test2"},
  {propertyA: "test3"}
];
$scope.filteredArray =[];
angular.forEach($scope.array,function(eachData){
   if(angular.isUndefined(eachData.propertyB))
   $scope.filteredArray.push(eachData);
});
```

And the `$scope.filteredArray` is array you want and you can use it in repeat for binding in html.

Answer (score 1):

you are adding a `filter` on `ng-repeat` so you will get a `collection`, as input to the filter, instead of a single array element so your implementation will not work.

as Kunal mentioned, try filtering the array before hand and repeat on filtered array.
or add a filter inside double curly braces `{{}}`.

check this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/e4HANvt4jiqR3hUvinWD?p=preview)

Comment: Please check the updated question. Also i want to filter the elements before i render them (in the ng-repeat)