# How to make angular empty filters match undefined and null values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I've found a problem while typing a filter and then remove it, the *collection* keeps being filtered and not showing the items with *undefined* or *null* values in the filtered term.

An example code:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppController as app">
<p>
Filters
</p>
    Name: <input ng-model="listFilters.name" type="text"/>
    <br/>
    Short Description: <input ng-model="listFilters.shortDescription" type="text"/>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in app.persons | filter:{name: listFilters.name, shortDescription: listFilters.shortDescription}">
            <p>{{person.name}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The angular code:

```
angular.module('App', []);
angular.module('App').controller('AppController', AppController);
function AppController() {
        var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.persons = [
        {
            name: 'Bill',
            shortDescription: null
        }, 
        {
            name: 'Sally',
            shortDescription: 'A girl'
        },
        {
            name: 'Jhon',
        },
    ];
}
```

A working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/89pkcww2/

Steps to see the problem I'm talking about:

1. Filter by name, the list is filtered.
2. Erase the filter, see how the list is again displayed (Bill, Sally, Jhon).
3. Filter by description, the list is filtered.
4. Erase the filter, only the second value of the collection is displayed (Sally) the ones with undefined or nulls aren't. It's filtering by "empty string".

I guess this is a *default* behavior in Angular filters but... is there a way to change it? Do I have to make my own filter?

I want to filter by both properties separately, the `collection | filter: filter.var` **does not** serve this purpose.

Nor this is the same as filtering to show only not null values, it's closer to the opposite...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-repeat filter for where an attribute is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177004/ng-repeat-filter-for-where-an-attribute-is-undefined)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25177318/4759033

Comment: I see no duplicate at all, it's more of an opposite functionality, I don't want to filter by *!!* or by *!null* I want to filter by the *value* that **is inside** the text input and, when It gets erased, I want to do **no filter** at all. So I need the filter to eval *'undefined'*, *null* and *''* (empty string) equally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. shortDescription: null , it doesnt mean '' , null != '' , so when you delete the text from the 'short description' it doesnt show 'Bill'     item.

   2. on third item there is not **shortDescription** at all so the `ng-model="listFilters.shortDescription"` cant bind to the property.
   3. only 'Sally' item works ok because the ng-model can bind to the property.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, I even clarified it at my description: *It's filtering by "empty string".* I want the **""**  (empty) filter to do no filters. So i get the element with the *'undefined'* shortDescription value and the **null** one.

Comment: So , you know what is the problem. It is easier to just add the property on all your items than creating a custom filter, although you can make a custom filter it is not a big deal.I could create an example.

Comment: I asked to know if there was a way to do it without writing a filter, nor adding the fields as empty strings, just with an angular *trick* or a functionality I was not aware of, but I guess there aren't any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Update your li html to something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in app.persons | filter:listFilters.name">
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/89pkcww2/1/

Comment: Wow that's a bit of a rebuild of the functionalities... I was filtering by the elements inside the *person* elements and I do want to keep that functionality, I can't use a general `collection | filter: some.filter`