# AngularJS filtering on ngRepeat on items without key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My array looks like this:

```
[
  {name:'John',IsManager:true},
  {name:'Terry'},
  {name:'Sam'},
  {name:'Andy'}
]
```

I'm trying to get it to display all the people that ***don't*** have the `IsManager` property: `Terry, Sam, and Andy`

Here's what I have so far:

```
<span ng-repeat="user in Users | filter: {?????}">
  {{user.name}}
</span>
```

How do I set up this filter? Can this be done without using a custom filter?

Comment: `<span ng-repeat="user in Users" ng-if="user.IsManager">`

Comment: <span ng-repeat="user in Users | filter: user.isManager">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**View:**

```
<span ng-repeat="user in Users | filter:filterOutNonManagers">
  {{user.name}}
</span>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.filterOutNonManagers = function(user) {
    return !user.IsManager;
};
```

Comment: I was hoping to keep it inline, but I guess I have to make a filter on the back end it seems. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177004/ng-repeat-filter-for-where-an-attribute-is-undefined

Comment: Just use an ng-if, if you want to keep it inline. `<div ng-repeat="user in users" ng-if="!user.IsManager">

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: (It doesn't work on Angular `1.3.15` due to a bug fixed in the next release [1.3.16](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1316-cookie-oatmealification-2015-06-05))

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

  $scope.Users = [{
    name: 'John',
    IsManager: true
  }, {
    name: 'Terry'
  }, {
    name: 'Sam'
  }, {
    name: 'Andy'
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">
  <span ng-repeat="user in Users | filter: {IsManager: '!'}">
      {{user.name}}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't work for my version of angular (1.3.15) though. This issue has also been raised in that link's comment.

Comment: Yes, there was a bug in 1.3.15 which was fixed in the next release only https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1316-cookie-oatmealification-2015-06-05

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/9dd0fe35d1027e59b84b2396abee00d8683f3b50

Comment: So consider upgrading your Angular. It works from 1.3.16 to 1.5.8. Cheers!

Comment: Haha I wish I could. I have no control on the angular version used on this project unfortunately.

Comment: Oh! Then you have no other option except using like others mentioned. 