# AngularJS remove NULL from ng-repeat

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I'm currently developing an AngularJS web application.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
List each item using the ng-repeat method and remove any null values.

**Correct** - One, Two, Three, Four
**Incorrect** - One, Two, Three, Four, Null (empty ng-repeat item)

**Current Problems:**
I've tried several methods todo this, including using the ng-hide function and creating a array filter but I can't seem to get either working correctly.

Any help / advice would be helpful!

**Array**

```
[ "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", null ]
```

**HTML:**

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in parseQ4P2 track by $index">
        <div class="md-list-item-text">
            <p>{{item}}</p>
        </div>
        <md-divider ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

**Failed Filter:**

```
dashApp.filter('removeBlackItems', function() {
  return function(inputArray) {
    var outArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
      if(inputArray[i].length !== 0){
        outArray.push(inputArray[i]);
      }
    }
    return outArray;
  };
});
```

Comment: Why your filter is failed? Can you give me a link to JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
.filter('emptyFilter', function() {
  return function(array) {
    var filteredArray = [];
      angular.forEach(array, function(item) {
        if (item) filteredArray.push(item);
      });
    return filteredArray;  
  };
}
```

**Controller JS:**

```
.filter('emptyFilter', function() {
  return function(array) {
    var filteredArray = [];
      angular.forEach(array, function(item) {
        if (item) filteredArray.push(item);
      });
    return filteredArray;  
  };
}
```

Anwser URL - [AngularJS remove empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067327/angularjs-remove-empty-value)

Answer (score 3):

You can filter data inside ng-repeat.
Try something like this: http://jsbin.com/sufexe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Could it be becuase I'm using Angular 1.4.4 ?

Comment: I've uploaded the project to Git - https://github.com/adamkwadsworth/Customer-Satisfaction-Survey-Dashboard/blob/master/app/src/widget_three.html

Answer (score 0):

as seen in [ng-repeat filter null value not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879507/ng-repeat-filter-null-value-not-displaying) there's no need for a custom filter. Ese angular's existing filter functionality to remove null objects from array in the template/view

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items| filter:{item:'!'} track by $index">
    <li>{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```