# AngularJS filter not blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have seen an answer on how to filter to "not null" but I need to know how to achieve a match on "not blank" instead.

I've tried

```
 $scope.sortedFieldsFilter = { SortMode: '!' }
 $scope.sortedFieldsFilter = { SortMode: "'!'" }
 $scope.sortedFieldsFilter = { SortMode: !'' }
```

And every other combination I can think of.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Filter empty objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991197/angularjs-filter-empty-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) tag to hide the empty/blank value, the element is shown when the expression evaluates to true, and an empty string will evaluate to false:

```
<div ng-show="yourVar">{{ yourVar }}</div>
```