# Filter out results with no value

Tags: angularjs

I've build a Angular function that allowes the user to do a search query using a inputfield. The user can search for a movie title and the function will do a request to TheMovieDB and returns a JSON file with the data.

```
$scope.search = function() {

  var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
  var service = '/search/movie';
  var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
  var search = $scope.searchquery
  var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
  var url = base + service + '?api_key=' + apiKey + search + '&callback=' + callback;

  $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

      if (status == 200) {
        $scope.movieList = data.results;
        console.log($scope.movieList)
      } else {
        console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
      }

    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
    });
}
```

Then I display that data in a template.

```
%div{"ng-controller" => "searchCtrl", :id => "container_search"}

  %input{"ng-change" => "search(searchquery)", "ng-model" => "searchquery", "ng-model-options" => "{ debounce: 500 }", :id => "search_input", :placeholder => "Search a movie!", "ng-keyup" => "clear_results()"}
  %ul#showresults
    %li.search_results{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList | orderBy:'-release_date'"}

      .addmovie{"ng-click" => "addMovie()"}
        %span
          Add Movie
      %img.poster{"ng-src" => "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{ movie.poster_path }}"}
      %span.title
        {{ movie.original_title }}
      %span.release
        {{ movie.release_date  | date:"yyyy" }}
      %span.movieID
        {{ movie.id }}
```

The problem is that some of the movies don't have a release date. I wish to filter out those results from the template. But I can't find a good example or tutorial on how to create this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

muenchdo's answer only works for null / undefined values...

I would use a ng-if directive taken from [AngularJS - Filter empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991197/angularjs-filter-empty-objects)
to have a more robust solution... (Cleanest way would probably be a filter but includes a lot more code)

Comment: This [issue comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11573#issuecomment-109975917) by an AngularJS contributor suggests either my solution or a custom filter.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a filter to your `ng-repeat`:

```
%li.search_results{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList | orderBy:'-release_date' | filter:{'release_date':''}"}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to remove the `-` , with the `-` it filters all the results.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thougt the release date property was named `-release_date`, forgetting that the `-` actually controls the sort order.

Comment: No problem, I thought I had to write a filter or something. Going to check the filter documentation for more of this stuff.