# AngularJS: ng-repeat, ng-if & JSON

Tags: html, json, angularjs, dom

I am having trouble with figuring out how to use `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` with JSON.  I want a `bar1` cluster to be displayed on the same line as a `bar2` cluster if they have the same name.

The JSON looks like so:

```
{
    "bar1" {
        "name": "bar1"
        "clusters": {
            "1": {
                "name": "Cluster 1"
            }
            ...
        }
    }
    "bar2" {
        "name": "bar2"
        "clusters": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Right now I have a terrible solution where I nested the `ng-repeat` for `bar2` inside the `ng-repeat` for `bar1`.  The correct cluster is being displayed, but, unfortunately, this still generates the HTML for all of the clusters that are being looped through in `bar2`. At the very least, I don't want that extra HTML to be generated.

**Angular**

```
<div ng-repeat="(bar1clusterKey, bar1clusterValue) in blah.bar1.clusters">
    <div>bar1 content</div>
    <div ng-repeat="(bar2clusterKey, bar2clusterValue) in blah.bar2.clusters">
        <div ng-if="bar1clusterValue.name == bar2clusterValue.name">
            <div>bar2 content on the same line as bar1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are more `bar1` clusters than `bar2` clusters, and `bar2` is a subset of `bar1`, so there aren't any unique `bar2` cluster names.

I have a few questions: Is there any way to achieve my desired outcome without generating extra HTML with `ng-repeat`?  Am I even using a sound nesting structure?  Can I take care of this by using a service (I haven't even written an Angular service yet)?

**EDIT:** Here is a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vkVcYpiVr5wBDgmtmN5l?p=preview) to show what I am talking about.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to organize your data in your html.  A better approach would be to organize it in your controller however you like, then have a simple html template to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the [`ng-if` on the same element as the `ng-repeat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783816/angular-ng-repeat-skip-an-item-if-it-matches-expression), then the HTML generated for all the items that don't match the `if` will be commented out by the looks of it, which isn't totally ideal but it gets the job done.  Perhaps a `remove()` could be piped in there somehow, but I didn't have any luck with that.

[The final Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vkVcYpiVr5wBDgmtmN5l?p=preview) and the key HTML snippet:

```
<div class="flex-container" ng-repeat="(bar2clusterKey, bar2clusterValue) in
blah.bar2.clusters" ng-if="bar1clusterValue.name == bar2clusterValue.name">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try angular `filter` to avoid `ng-if`

```
<div ng-repeat="(bar1clusterKey, bar1clusterValue) in blah.bar1.clusters">
    <div>bar1 content</div>
    <div ng-repeat="bar2 in blah.bar2.clusters| filter: {name: bar2clusterValue.name}">
         <div>bar2 content on the same line as bar1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried using filter in at least 7 different ways, but none of them worked. :(

Comment: I tried that too, no luck.  Maybe it's a problem with my JSON... I don't know.  If I find a solution I'll be sure to post it.  Thanks for the filter idea.  I'll continue down that path.

Comment: @UltraSonja could you create plunkr..then that would be great to further deep dive

Comment: I can do that tomorrow.  There's a more pressing issue I have to solve today.

Comment: Apparently you can't filter on objects in Angular, only arrays.  I got this error: `Error: [filter:notarray]`, which lead me to this [github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9992), and [this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray).

Comment: I created a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vkVcYpiVr5wBDgmtmN5l?p=preview) this morning.  Will experiment throughout the day.  If you inspect the HTML output source code, you can see that for each bar1 cluster, there are 2 bar2 clusters being created even though only 1 is being displayed.  I want to remove the extra cluster.  There's a jqLite remove() method, but I'm not sure if that's what I want or how to instantiate it in the DOM.