# ng-repeat for various json object with different values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

here's the problem. I have this poorly developed json file in which there are 3 different object for each area. Here is an example.

```
{
    "gebieden":"Antwerpen",
    "onderwerpen":"Gemiddeld netto inkomen per belastingsplichtige",
    "data_2005":"15084,8252887",
    "data_2006":"14935,2782929",
    "data_2007":"15353,0192747",
    "data_2008":"16040,981705",
    "data_2009":"16050,4881554",
    "data_2010":"15777,0232385",
    "data_2011":"16487,8501985"
},
{
    "gebieden":"Antwerpen",
    "onderwerpen":"Mediaan netto inkomen",
    "data_2005":"11424",
    "data_2006":"11194",
    "data_2007":"11445",
    "data_2008":"12208",
    "data_2009":"12316",
    "data_2010":"12211",
    "data_2011":"12788"
},
{
    "gebieden":"Antwerpen",
    "onderwerpen":"Aantal belastingsplichtigen",
    "data_2005":"129568",
    "data_2006":"137614",
    "data_2007":"141273",
    "data_2008":"142771",
    "data_2009":"146058",
    "data_2010":"151516",
    "data_2011":"151674"
}
```

notice how these 3 objects have the same value for the property `"gebieden"` but a different value for the property `"onderwerpen"`
Now I have managed to show all areas in a an accordion group like this :

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="item in All | unique:'gebieden'">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="{{item.gebieden}}" href="#{{$index}}">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                {{item.gebieden}}
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="{{$index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                            <div class="panel-body text-center">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li ng-repeat="item in All | unique:'onderwerpen'">
                                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#{{item.onderwerpen}}">
                                            {{item.onderwerpen}}
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content" style="padding:2%">
                                    <div id="{{item.onderwerpen}}" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th class="text-center">Jaar</th>
                                                    <th class="text-center">Waarde</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="(key,val) in item | comparator" ng-hide="$index<2" >
                                                    <td>{{key}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{val}}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

As you can see I have implemented a tab layout for the panel-body and managed to make a tab for each value `"onderwerpen"`there is in the entire JSON. but how do I access the data for these different object, as I am using `unique`filter to avoid double data from showing. how can I make only the data from the object with property value `"onderwerpen" = chosen tab`show? 
I'm not sure if my question is clear enough, if not don't hesitate to tell me and ask more information.
Thank you.

Comment: read [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783816/angular-ng-repeat-skip-an-item-if-it-matches-expression)
I think you can use ng-if to filter some objects

Comment: Why not use `filter` on your items. As a condition to pass you take your choosen tab.

Comment: I understand, and I have thought about that but I really have no clue how to do this? :/

Comment: @ShyA I have looked into this, but I can't seem to find the structure in how to use in in my case?

Comment: @LordTribual any chance you can tell me how to do the ng-repeat for data in selected `onderwerpen` tab ?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `filter` to filter out the object based on the tab clicked. Here is a working fiddle that displays the properties based on the tab clicked - http://jsfiddle.net/uwpjk28w/12/

So, basically I added a `ng-click` function that changes the `onderwerpen` property.

```
<a data-toggle="tab" ng-click="setOnderwerpen(item.onderwerpen)">
     {{item.onderwerpen}}
</a>
```

The function that changes the `onderwerpen`:

```
 $scope.selectedOnderwerpen = '';
 $scope.setOnderwerpen = function (onderwerpen) {
        $scope.selectedOnderwerpen = onderwerpen;
 }
```

And the filter:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in All | filter {onderwerpen:selectedOnderwerpen}:true">
      <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in item" ng-show="$index < 7">
           <td>{{key}}</td>
           <td>{{value}}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Also, used ng-show to show the table only when you have selected a tab.

```
ng-show="selectedOnderwerpen!=''"
```

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Wow, yes this helps me out, thank you very much. Now I just want to know, is it possible to use databinding inside the filter like such `| filter {onderwerpen: {{parentscope.onderwerpen}}}:true` or does this not work?

Comment: For the `<div class="tab-pane ...">` I tried to make the ID unique by using `id="ond{{$index}}"` but this only works for the first collapse so all other collapses will not work. I tried using the `$index` from the parent scope but that didn't work. have any ideq on how to create an automatic unique id for these tags?

Comment: I added another part of my JSON into your fiddle and as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tom_EMK/uwpjk28w/15/  It never retrieves the correct data for the second panel content (if you understand what I'm trying to say?)

Comment: Could you also explain why your Accordion works correctly but mine will just open all panes instead of closing other ones, when opening a new one

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helps. Regarding your first question, are you trying to use a variable from the parent scope? If so, you could use it like this - `| filter {onderwerpen: {$parent.onderwerpen}}:true`. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Regarding your second question, the reason why the ID is not unique in `<div class="tab-pane ...">` is because this div is looped over based on the number of unique `onderwerpen`, so it's iterated over only once. To make this unique, replace `<div id="{{item.onderwerpen}}"` with `<div id="{{selectedOnderwerpen}}"`, so whenever you click on a tab, the ID is updated based on the tab's `onderwerpen` value. Here's the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uwpjk28w/20/. Hope this makes sense and answers your question. Please let me know if not.

Comment: it does make sense, although some of the `'onderwerpen'`values contain spaces and can therefor never be assigned to an id. Second, Again I added another part of the original json that I'm working with, so that there's to panels. And I'm not able to read the correct data for the second panel. I'm only able to retrieve the data for first panel, and fill it in in every table. http://jsfiddle.net/Tom_EMK/uwpjk28w/25/

Comment: Ah yes, to have the second panel render data correctly, I chained filter together like this - `<tbody ng-repeat="item in All | filter:{onderwerpen:selectedOnderwerpen}:true | filter:{gebieden:selectedGebieden}:true">`. Here's the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uwpjk28w/31/. So, whenever you click on `gebieden`, I reset `onderwerpen` and set `gebieden` using a function. Also, I show the table only when both `onderwerpen` and `gebieden` are set like this - `ng-show="selectedOnderwerpen!='' && selectedGebieden!=''"`. Hope this helps :). Let me know if not.

Comment: thenk you so much! the only problem I'm having now Is that my accordion isn't working appropriatly it's not closing other opened panel when i open a new one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100715/discussion-between-tom-kustermans-and-sabarish-senthilnathan).

Comment: No problem! Can you show what you mean? Isn't 'Antwerpen' tab closing when you click on 'Berendrecht Zandvliet Lillo' and vice-versa? Also updated to fiddle to have a unique id number for `<div class="tab-pane ...">`  - http://jsfiddle.net/uwpjk28w/34/. Basically I get the index of the selected `gebieden` and `onderwerpen` when you click on a `onderwerpen` and the div id is updated.

Comment: yes indeed that is what's happening, but for some reason this works on fiddler, but not on my page? I think it had something to do with the databinding or the ng-repeat, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

I think that i you could modify the json like this:

```
{
   "gebieden":"Antwerpen",
   "onderwerpen":"Gemiddeld netto inkomen per belastingsplichtige",
   "data":{
      "data_2005":"15084,8252887",
      "data_2006":"14935,2782929",
      "data_2007":"15353,0192747",
      "data_2008":"16040,981705",
      "data_2009":"16050,4881554",
      "data_2010":"15777,0232385",
      "data_2011":"16487,8501985"
   }
},
{
   "gebieden":"Antwerpen",
   "onderwerpen":"Mediaan netto inkomen",
   "data":{
      "data_2005":"11424",
      "data_2006":"11194",
      "data_2007":"11445",
      "data_2008":"12208",
      "data_2009":"12316",
      "data_2010":"12211",
      "data_2011":"12788"
   }
},
{
   "gebieden":"Antwerpen",
   "onderwerpen":"Aantal belastingsplichtigen",
   "data":{
      "data_2005":"129568",
      "data_2006":"137614",
      "data_2007":"141273",
      "data_2008":"142771",
      "data_2009":"146058",
      "data_2010":"151516",
      "data_2011":"151674"
   }
}
```

You can get the data in a good way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="item in All">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="{{item.gebieden}}" href="#{{$index}}">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                {{item.gebieden}}
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="{{$index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                            <div class="panel-body text-center">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li>
                                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#{{item.onderwerpen}}">
                                            {{item.onderwerpen}}
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content" style="padding:2%">
                                    <div id="{{item.onderwerpen}}" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th class="text-center">Jaar</th>
                                                    <th class="text-center">Waarde</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="(key,val) in item.data" ng-hide="$index<2" >
                                                    <td>{{key}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{val}}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Check this working example on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iIuPINSLkBXaqcjV24wg?p=preview)

Comment: I am not able to edit the JSON because I parsed it from an open dataset with nodejs and passed it to my frontend